# How to fire two functions on single button click

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello stackoverflow community I am having problem in using onpress method. Actually i want to fire two functions on a single button click like if i press Register button the validate() function and userRegister function works first validate function validate all the fields and then register function registers user into db. I seen setState is responsible for this kind of behaviour since i m new in react native development so i cant implement this kind of functionality 
my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {ToastAndroid, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class Project extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserName: '',
      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: '',
      cpassword: "",
      UserCity: ''

    };

  }

  Validate=()=>{
    if(this.state.UserName == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter UserName',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserEmail == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Email',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserPassword == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Password',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.cpassword == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Confirm Password',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if (this.state.UserPassword != this.state.cpassword){
      ToastAndroid.show('Password did not match',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserCity == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter City Name',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else {
      ToastAndroid.show('User Registration Sucessfull', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    console.log(this.state)
  }

UserRegistrationFunction = () =>{
    const {UserName} = this.state;
    const {UserEmail} = this.state;
    const {UserPassword} = this.state;
    const {UserCity} = this.state;


  fetch('http://192.168.0.107/loginrn/user_registration.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },

    body: JSON.stringify({

      name: this.state.UserName,


      email: this.state.UserEmail,

      password: this.state.UserPassword,

      //confpassword: this.state.cpassword
      city : this.state.UserCity,


    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {


  // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.

        Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

}

  render() {

    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style= {styles.title}>User Registration Form</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Name"
          onChangeText={name => this.setState({UserName : name})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Email"
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({UserEmail : email})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Password"
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({UserPassword : password})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />
           <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={cpassword => this.setState({cpassword})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User City Name"
          onChangeText={city => this.setState({UserCity : city})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />
        <Button title="Click Here To Register"  
        onPress={this.Validate}
        color="#2196F3" />
        <Button title = "Next" onPress={this.UserRegistrationFunction} color = "#2196F3"/>



</View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you not just call a function that calls these 2 functions?

Comment: `onPress={this.Validate}` pass a different function into `onPress` which calls two functions?

Comment: Because i write web api in php and using db as mysql

Comment: @evolutionxbox i mean to say i want to fire two functions behind one button press currently i have two different button but i want functionality like when i press registrer button validate function validate all text fields then register function registers the user into db

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned below, You can call two function like this (in class component)

```
login=()=>{
    console.log('login')
  }

register =()=>{
    console.log('register')
  }
```

```
 <Button title = "Next" onPress={()=>[this.user(),this.register()]}/>
```

According to your requirement, You should use something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    date: '',
    month: '',
    year: '',
    isErrorDate: false,
    isErrorDateLenght: false,
    isErrorMonth: false,
    isErrorMonthLength: false,
    isErrorYear: false,
    isErrorYearLength: false,
  };

  onChangeDate = value => {
    this.setState({
      date: value,
      isErrorDate: false,
      isErrorDateLenght: false,
    });
  };
  onChangeMonth = value => {
    this.setState({
      month: value,
      isErrorMonth: false,
      isErrorMonthLength: false,
    });
  };
  onChangeYear = value => {
    this.setState({
      year: value,
      isErrorYear: false,
      isErrorYearLength: false,
    });
  };

  doRegister = () => {
    console.log('you have registered');
  };

  checkDate = () => {

      //validation part or function

    const { date, month, year } = this.state;
    let isErrorDate = date.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorDateLenght =
      date.length > 2 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(date) || date > 31 ? true : false;
    let isErrorMonth = month.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorMonthLength =
      month.length > 2 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(month) || month > 12 ? true : false;
    let isErrorYear = year.trim() === '' ? true : false;
    let isErrorYearLength =
      year.length > 4 || !/^[0-9]+$/.test(year) ? true : false;

    if (
      isErrorDate ||
      isErrorDateLenght ||
      isErrorMonth ||
      isErrorMonthLength ||
      isErrorYear ||
      isErrorYearLength
    ) {
      this.setState({
        isErrorDate: isErrorDate,
        isErrorDateLenght: isErrorDateLenght,
        isErrorMonth: isErrorMonth,
        isErrorMonthLength: isErrorMonthLength,
        isErrorYear: isErrorYear,
        isErrorYearLength: isErrorYearLength,
      });
      Alert.alert('invalid date /month/ year');
    } else {

      //submit date and call other functions
      this.doRegister();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View>
          <View>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="DD"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                value={this.state.date}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeDate}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="MM"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                value={this.state.month}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeMonth}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
              <TextInput
                placeholder="AA"
                keyboardType="number-pad"
                value={this.state.year}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeYear}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Button title ="Next" onPress={this.checkDate}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Change this according to your requirement. Feel free for doubts

Comment: if i do this thing which u post here it fires both functions simultaneously but i want to stop registration function untill full validation complete then register the user

Comment: I edited my answer with a new code. which i have used for another project. i think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Pass the validate function to onPress = {()=> this.validate()}
And then pass the UserRegistrationFunction in validate function at the end.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {ToastAndroid, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, Alert } from 'react-native';

export default class Project extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserName: '',
      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: '',
      cpassword: "",
      UserCity: ''

    };

  }

  Validate=()=>{
    if(this.state.UserName == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter UserName',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserEmail == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Email',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserPassword == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Password',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.cpassword == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Confirm Password',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if (this.state.UserPassword != this.state.cpassword){
      ToastAndroid.show('Password did not match',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else if(this.state.UserCity == ""){
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter City Name',ToastAndroid.SHORT)
    }
    else {
      this.UserRegistrationFunction();
    }
    console.log(this.state)
  }

UserRegistrationFunction = () =>{
    const {UserName} = this.state;
    const {UserEmail} = this.state;
    const {UserPassword} = this.state;
    const {UserCity} = this.state;


  fetch('http://192.168.0.107/loginrn/user_registration.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    },

    body: JSON.stringify({

      name: this.state.UserName,


      email: this.state.UserEmail,

      password: this.state.UserPassword,

      //confpassword: this.state.cpassword
      city : this.state.UserCity,


    })
  }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {


  // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.

        Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

}

  render() {

    return (

<View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <Text style= {styles.title}>User Registration Form</Text>

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Name"
          onChangeText={name => this.setState({UserName : name})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Email"
          onChangeText={email => this.setState({UserEmail : email})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Password"
          onChangeText={password => this.setState({UserPassword : password})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />
           <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={cpassword => this.setState({cpassword})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter User City Name"
          onChangeText={city => this.setState({UserCity : city})}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
          //secureTextEntry={true}
          />
        <Button title="Click Here To Register"  
        onPress={()=>this.Validate()}
        color="#2196F3" />
        <Button title = "Next" onPress={this.UserRegistrationFunction} color = "#2196F3"/>



</View>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if i do this thing which u post here it fires both functions simultaneously but i want to stop registration function untill full validation complete then register the user

Comment: Ive Checked this program on my local machine. Its working as per your requirements. Please try once this code.. Copy paste with your original.

Comment: Yes now its work fine but i want to fire both of functions from signal button click  eg if i click on register button first validate function fire if any field is empty it shows prompt after validation is complete then registration function register the user.

Comment: Its working as per your wish only.. You just have to click register button then both the functions are called simultaneously..